# Why don't I hit the campgrounds/edit page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Here is a get route and I have stored the previous link where it was redirected from in the
**req.session** object under **returnTo**. After redirecting it hits the **/login** and we can see the object in the console.

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('get in user route..', req.session)
    res.render('users/login')
})
```

```
req.session :
```

[image: The req.session object]

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {
    req.flash('success', 'Welcome back!')
    const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/campgrounds'
    res.redirect(redirectUrl)
})
```

But after submitting the login details it always goes to the **/campgrounds** route.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer after referring to the new **passport.js** version. In the newer version the session id is updated. So I no longer have access to it. So, what I did is I declared a variable

```
let ran = ''
```

and stored `res.locals.returnTo` in  `ran` variable.

```
res.locals.returnTo = req.session.returnTo
    ran = req.session.returnTo
    res.render('users/login')
```

So, we have access to the **retrun to url** even if the seesion id is updated.